# How to invoke a control within a class

Tags: c#

I have a windows form with a button.
I click the button and it starts a method in a separate class. I start this method in a separate thread.

When this class.method finishes it raises an event back to the windows form class.

When this happens I start another method in that separate class that tells a system.windows.form timer (declared in that class) to be enabled and thus start processing.

But the timer does not start (I did put a break point inside the 'tick' event).

I am assuming that it is because I declared the timer outside of the calling thread right at the start of my code.

Normally, I would use this to invoke a method on the same thread...

this.invoke(mydelegatename, any pars);

But, 'this' cannot be called with an class because unassumingly it is related to the UI thread.

I know this all looks bad architecture and I can easily solve this problem by moving the timer to the UI thread (windows form class).

But, I have forgotten how I did this many years ago and it really is an attempt to encapsulate my code.

Can anyone enlighten me pls?

Thanks

The Code:

**[windows class]**

```
_webSync = new WebSync(Shared.ClientID);
_webSync.evBeginSync += new WebSync.delBeginSync(_webSync_evBeginSync);
Thread _thSync = new Thread(_webSync.PreConnect);
_thSync.Start();


private void _webSync_evBeginSync()
{
_webSync.Connect();
}
```

**[WebSync class]**

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _tmrManifestHandler = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
public WebSyn()
{
_tmrManifestHandler.Tick += new EventHandler(_tmrManifestHandler_Tick);
_tmrManifestHandler.Interval = 100;
_tmrManifestHandler.Enabled = false;
}


public delegate void delBeginSync();
public event delBeginSync evBeginSync;

public void PreConnect()
{
  while (true)
   {
     if (some condition met)
     {
      evBeginSync();
      return ;
     }
   }       
}

public void Connect()
{          
  _tmrManifestHandler.Enabled = true;
  _tmrManifestHandler.Start();
}

private void _tmrManifestHandler_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //NOT BEING 'HIT'
}
```

Comment: Show us your current code. It is incredibly difficult to understand what you are doing without some code to show.

Comment: LOL - I realised your point when I re-read my post! 10 secs..

Comment: took longer than I thought

Comment: consider rewriting the code to use Tasks and lambdas instead of Threads and delegates/events.

Comment: in [windows class] you are creating WebSync but your constructor is named "WebSyn" are those the same classes?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments.  It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. In regards to using tasks and lambdas  It is a question of preference for me.  I prefer delegates and threads :)

Comment: If you know both technologies and prefer delegates/threads, then thats fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer on another thread will not work.

[for more info look here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Use a System.Timers.Timer instead, be carefull of CrossThreadExceptions if you are using accessing UI elements.

```
public class WebSync
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _tmrManifestHandler = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public WebSync(object id)
    {
        _tmrManifestHandler.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_tmrManifestHandler_Tick);
        _tmrManifestHandler.Interval = 100;
        _tmrManifestHandler.Enabled = false;
    }

    public delegate void delBeginSync();
    public event delBeginSync evBeginSync;

    public void PreConnect()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (true /* just for testing*/)
            {
                evBeginSync();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        _tmrManifestHandler.Enabled = true;
        _tmrManifestHandler.Start();
    }

    private void _tmrManifestHandler_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //NOT BEING 'HIT'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `_tmrManifestHandler.Start()`; enabling is not enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I just did that but it still does not work.